# How to make if condition word found in array

Tags: php, arrays, string, conditional-statements

In PHP

```
echo $avatar["name"];
$array = ["hello", "world", "!"];
$string = "wor";
if (in_array($string, [$array])){
    echo "match";
}else
    echo "not match";
```

I want a script like that to print match if the word found in array , not string equal to array

Comment: I removed the JS tag as it seems unrelated to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this :

```
function partial_array_search( $array, $keyword ) {
    $found = [];
    // Loop through each item and check for a match.
    foreach ( $array as $string ) {
        // If found somewhere inside the string, add.
        if ( strpos( $string, $keyword ) !== false ) {
            $found[] = $string;
        }
    }
    return $found;
}

$array = ["hello", "world", "!"];
$string = "wor";

$data = partial_array_search( $array, $string );
if($data){
    print_r($data) ;   
}else{
    echo 'NOT MATCH';
}
```